# Error: 421 Timeout waiting for data from client using express-mailer with attachments

Tags: node.js, email, express, amazon-ses

I'm using `express-mailer` (which built on top of `nodemailer`) to send email from my `nodejs` app. If I send a plain html email, it works just fine, but if I try to attach files, I get `Error: 421 Timeout waiting for data from client`.

Note that that error only shows up when I use Amazon SES as the smtp server. If I use another email server, the email gets sent. I have tried to google the problem and I have found no answer. Can someone help me?

This is my code:

```
var mailer = require('express-mailer');
mailer.extend(app, {
    from: 'No Reply <no-reply@no-reply.com>',
    host: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    secureConnection: false,
    port: 587,
    transportMethod: 'SMTP',
    auth: {
        user: 'user',
        pass: 'password'
    }
});

var mailConfig = {
    to: 'me@email.com',
    subject: 'email_subject',
    data: {
        name: 'name'
    }
};

var sendOptions = {
    template: 'emailTemplate',
    attachments: [{
        fileName: 'attachment.pdf', filePath: 'data/attachment.pdf'}
    }]
};

app.mailer.send(sendOptions, mailConfig, function (err) 
{
    if (err)
        console.log(err + '\n' + __filename + ' ' + __functionName + ' ' + __lineNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I just change the `port` to `465` and the `secureConnection` to `true`.